# How to correctly use the mirror modifier?

Tags: modifiers, mirror

I have some problems with the mirror modifier.
I think it doesn't mirror in the right way.

[image]
as you can see the two outlined objects face in the same direction. I want they face each others.
Is that possible?
Also when i move one outwards they moves in the same direction, instead i want they get far away.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed possible :).

1) Choose the right axis
There are three axis to mirror around.
Trial and error will get you there fast enough :).
[image]

2) Don't move the object, move the mesh.
The mirroring center is your object's *origin point*.
So instead of moving your object, switch to *Edit Mode* and move your mesh farther from the *origin point*.

[image]

3) Apply rotation
Object's local rotation can mess with modifiers.
Go to *Object->Apply->Rotation*.
[image]

Further Reading:
[Mirror Modifier page in Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/mirror.html)